# Can MS SQL Management Studio 2012 be installed without installing SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, windows

We have a windows server 2012 with SQL Server 2012 BI installed.

I can remote desktop and use the sql management studio in the server. However I would like to install that tool - sql management studio 2012 - in my local machine, but I don't see a need for the sql server.

Can I install the tool only??

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can run the installer on your local machine. During the feature selection dialog, select "Management Tools - Basic" or "Management Tools - Complete" based on what you need.

Launch the install from the CD/ISO:

Then go to Installation > New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing environment. 
[image]

Proceed with next through the next few boxes, even the **Install Setup Files**

Once complete you will see the below image, click next to proceed:
[image]
You can then install either basic or complete management tools as shown. Select and click next
[image]

As you can see it is only installing the Management Tools you selected:

[image]

Click install and you're all set.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.
The first question in the wizard, is: New SQL Server Stand-alone - OR - Upgrade from SQL Server 2005, 2008 etc

Before hitting any of these two, I am already believing I will endup with SQL Server installed!

Comment: @user1166999 I updated my answer with a walkthrough.

Comment: Thank you for the images. I am installing SQL Management Studio at the moment. I am still doubtful as a shared feature that could not be ticked out is 'Local DB', but I do need the tool.

Comment: The older SQL installers were a lot better in this regard. A screen very early in the installer would ask if you were setting up server, client or both. I think this whole question flows from the poor usability of the recent SQL Server installers.

Comment: Hi, I realised I never did provide feedback after installing. I just went trough the instalation and had no SQL server. So I do thank you :)

Shame, a couple of months after I did install visual studio and ended up with SQL Server anyway :/ 

Ow well...

Comment: Our (SQL 2012) setup program has no "Ready to Install" step and doesn't show you whether or not it's installing a DB server :-(